# Mount ISO over HTTP

Tags: windows, http, optical-media, iso

I have a large number of CDs and DVDs, some freeware, but also commercial software for which I own a license. The total size of these is > 150 GB, so I don't have a USB stick (yet) for carrying them all with me. Even if I had such a USB stick, I'll probably just don't have it with me when I need it.

On the other hand side, I have a huge hard disk in my web server where I could store such ISOs and they are accessible via HTTP.

Now I'm looking for a tool

- for Windows
- that can mount ISO files (CD and DVD) on the client
- via HTTP (that's what the server supports)
- and does not download the whole ISO in advance but downloads only those parts which are needed/accessed by the client

I prefer free software, but I'd even spend 30 € for such an application.

I'm not so sure, but it seems [HTTPFS](http://httpfs.sourceforge.net/) could do it on Linux.

I have tried [HttpDisk](http://www.acc.umu.se/~bosse/), but it's too complex to install. It needs enabling Windows driver testing, disabling integrity checks etc., thus exposing security risks. I've tried all that in a virtual machine, but it failed on Windows 7 x64 with a `System error 127 - the prodecure could not be found`.

As suggested in the comments, I have tried

- [WinCDEmu](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/wincdemu-portable) Portable, which can open ISO files from a HTTP server if you copy/paste the full URL into the file open dialog. Unfortunately this downloads the whole ISO in advance, so it does not fit my needs.

Comment: WinCDEMU may work.  It's available in both installed and portable versions.  I have not used it.  A fast read of its descriptions does not talk about remote access.  If you could map your remote ISO to a drive letter, I suspect it would work.  It mounts the ISO, no clue about your last bullet.  http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/wincdemu-portable   OR http://wincdemu.sysprogs.org/  It does require admin rights.

Comment: @JKEngineer: "WinCDEmu is [...] a tool that allows you to mount optical disc images by simply clicking on them in Windows Explorer." - but how do I get it into Windows Explorer via HTTP?

Comment: I was not sure, to be honest so I tried and succeeded with the following.  I put a test iso file in a directory on a website that I control.  I loaded WinCDEMU, hit Mount Image, and pasted the entire path: http://www.domain.com/directory/filename.iso into the open file dialog.  It appears to work.  The next window that opens is the Win Dialog asking if I want to open files to explore the disk or run the executable on it.  Try that if it is an accessible method for you.  If not, can you map the remote directory to a drive letter?

Comment: Note for the above. Include both http: & //www. - does not show in the displayed answer.      Also the comment seems to have lost @Thomas Weller

Comment: @JKEngineer: thanks for clarification. I tried with a 50 MB test ISO and monitored it with Process Monitor. It downloaded ~50k Packets @ 1452 bytes, giving 72 MB. This looks like 50 MB + some HTTP overhead, so unfortunately it does not fit the criterion "does not download everything in advance".

Comment: I'd suggest trying it again with a couple of different types of iso files - such as a bootable for one, and a simple assembly of files like doc or pdf, and seeing what happens.  I am not sure what has to happen when you try to mount a disk image - how much info has to be provided to the system.  Let us know!   I see you have edited your question in a way that makes my comments seem like after thoughts.  I think you should edit your edit to reflect that you are reacting to the comments.   I also wonder if I should convert my series of comments to answers. (How to do that?)

Comment: @JKEngineer: done. Comments are meant to be temporary, that's why I have copied it to the question. Of course it has to read some information in advance, perhaps the file names, but it should not read a whole 3 GB DVD in advance. You cannot convert comments to an answer. You would need to copy/paste and then delete the comment. I'd suggest not to do so, since it might be downvoted unless it fits the "does not download everything in advance" requirement.